# What determines how quickly a ship repairs?

Tags: galactic-civilizations-3

After a battle, more often than not a player's ships can become quite damaged and will take a lengthy amount of time to repair.  The regular repair rate for a ship seems to be about 1hp per turn, but I'm not at all sure if this is the norm and what factors affect how quickly a ship is repaired.

What are the rules around ship repair?

Does returning a ship to a starbase, shipyard, planet or friendly territory cause a ship to repair faster?  If so by what degree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a response to the post ["quickest way to regenerate ship health?"](http://steamcommunity.com/app/226860/discussions/1/620713633851536004/) in the *[Gal Civ 3 steam forum](http://steamcommunity.com/app/226860/discussions/)*:

> Sitting/moving in space repairs 0.75 to 1.25 points per turn (every
>   third turn you get zero, one or two points depending on your repair
>   rate). Orbiting a planet repairs at 4 x this rate (three to five
>   points per turn). Shipyards and star bases are almost as fast as
>   planets for repair.
>
> Faster repair times are available via research; however, they become
>   available in the mid to late game period.

This is the closest I've found yet about the official repair rules.